# Is the AC for this Genasi swordmage correct?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

So we have this character one of my players is bringing to my sessions, and I wanted to check if it works out like he thinks it does (stats are rolled):

Genasi Swordmage (PP Elemental Tempest) level 12

18 Str
14 Con
12 Dex
23 Int
10 Wis
13 Cha

Feats

1. Eyes in the back of your head
2. Fiery Blood
3. Elemental Echo
4. Toughness
5. Intelligent Blademaster
6. Extra manifestation
7. Shocking Flame
8. Greater Swordmage Warding

Equipment

1. Body : Drowmesh armor +3
2. Weapon : Flaming Broadsword +2
3. Arms : Bracers of mighty striking (Paragon)
4. Hands : Gauntlets of Blood (Paragon)
5. Neck : Cloak of Translocation +2

Defenses

- AC : 28
- Fort : 24
- Ref : 27
- Will : 22

The defenses above are from the character generator. My own calculations are in the question below.

- **Is this the correct AC: 10 + 6 [1/2 level] + 5 [Leather + 3] + 6 [Int mod] + 1 [Greater swordmage warding] = 28?**
- **Is swordmage warding an ability that needs to be activated or is it always active?**
- **Why is greater swordmage warding already accounted for in these stats, but swordmage warding isn't?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The character needs to equip their sword

Having rebuilt the character in question myself, I've noticed that the bonus from Greater Swordmage Warding applies at all times, even if it shouldn't (i.e. when you aren't getting the normal Swordmage Warding bonus). However, the basic Swordmage Warding benefit is controlled by which items you currently have equipped in the builder. If you equip your sword in your main hand, you should receive the extra +3 from Swordmage Warding.

Granted, this is just a guess at the problem, but from the situation, it seems to me like the most likely solution.

As far as Swordmage Warding goes: you don't need to activate it, it's constantly active as long as you're conscious and wielding either a light blade or a heavy blade (hence the above problem). The bonus is +3 to AC if you have one hand free, otherwise it's only +1.